# Format issues with code

Tags: discussion

I have noticed that when using code for multiple lines there is an extra grey/gray area(s), and space when encountering a new line.

Example:

```
<code>This is a sample
of what the issue
is when using

multiple lines.
</code>
```

Results:

`This is a sample
of what the issue 
is when using`

multiple lines.

I don't know if it is interpreting a newline as a character, or EOL as a character, but this is a problem if you wish to do a large block (with empty lines). I am unsure if this is intentional, or if it needs to be tweaked.

### Adding edit to show `<pre>`

```
This is a sample
of what the issue 
is when using

multiple lines.
```

(added `<pre>` tags after `<code>` tags.)
I have looked in a different browser (Iceweasel) and it is slightly less annoying vs. Chrome (first space is smaller in Iceweasel).

Comment: I don't think this is a bug. `<code>` can be used for inline code as well as block. If you want block formatting you need to wrap it in `<pre>` though. Please try to avoid HTML in posts though, it makes editing hard.

Answer (score 2):

It's not a bug, you're using code wrong. You need to wrap `<code>` in `<pre>` blocks. `<pre><code>Hello World</code></pre>`. This is demonstrated if you hover over the "Preformatted text" button.

[image]

You should really be using Markdown though, HTML is not really supported or guartenteed to work.